# Why does the author use past simple here?

Tags: past-tense

Collectively, as Swell Maps, we **released** two albums which had sold enough copies to reach the top of the UK independent album charts, so we had saved up some shared royalties from records sales. We had recorded most of that material at John Rivers'Woodbine studios on his TEAC  four-track tape machine. When he upgraded to an eight-track, we used  some of those funds to buy his old TEAC four-track tape deck

Jowe Head    from the book  Swell Maps 1972 1980

Why is it not written " had released'? What seems  important for me  in this sentence  is not when it was released  but the fact it had been released . However  it is true that later some compilations would be out.
This event like the others after happened before the band (Swell Maps) bought the TEAC four-track tape machine . All are in past perfect except this one why?

Comment: "We released two albums which had sold X copies" doesn't make sense - presumably just an error.

Comment: That is what I think but was waiting for a confirmation

Comment: You're right - it would work with re-released.